# ultimo item da lista <li> não fica em baixo mesmo tendo espaço

Tags: html, css, lista

Estou fazendo um site bem simples em HTML5 e CSS puro

Então eu criei uma lista inline-block de 4 itens e cada item é um quadrado grande cujos tamanhos tem que se alinhar ao cabeçalho e tal. O problema é que quando vou definir o tamanho certo para alinhar com a interface do site o ultimo item da lista vai pra baixo mesmo sobrando espaço pra ele ficar em cima...

Já tentei fazer com divs ao invés de lista e da a mesma coisa. Entao eu coloquei uma borda branca na interface so pra vcs verem o tamanho dela

1) exemplo: lista alinhada porém só a esquerda
http://www.emagrecerdireito.com/agency/

2) exemplo: então se eu aumento os blocos para alinharem a direita o ultimo cai pra baixo
http://www.emagrecerdireito.com/agency2/

Já, nesse caso estou aumentando o tamanho à esquerda com padding-left(de 11,7% para 12%), mas ja tentei com width e da o mesmo efeito e o mesmo problema.

O id que formata os Blocos é o "#interfaceiconesprodutos li"

Comment: O bloco está caindo pois o tamanho do container não o está comportando. Pelo que eu vi no DOM e no CSS, o posicionamento do `<figure id="logo">` está errado, comprometendo a `<figure>` interna e, assim, impactando na visualização dos produtos.

Comment: Além disso, a tag `<head>` está no lugar errado.

Comment: @Rodrigo Rigotti, eu consertei o header*, agora está indo de boa nem mexi no figure. O que há de errado nele?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O teu problema é o *whitespace* entre as `li`.

Como tens um `padding` à direita que somado com o `padding` à esquerda resulta em 25%, o *whitespace* aumentar o consumo um pouco e a soma das quatro `li` que já é 100% com a adição do *whitespace* ultrapassa os 100% disponíveis.

## Como resolver

Podes resolver a questão de diversas maneiras:

1. Acabar com o *whitespace*

   O espaço aparece porque existe pelo menos um caracteres entre as `li`, quer seja tabulação quer seja quebra de linha ou outros.

   Se tiveres o código HTML todo seguido já resolves a questão:

   ```html
   <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
   ```
2. Ajustar as definições de CSS

   Podes ajustar o teu `padding-right` que está a `13%` para `12.333%` de forma a retirar da `li` aquilo que o *whitespace* está a consumir.
3. Ajustar apresentação dos elementos

   Estas a definir nas `li` a propriedade `display: inline-block;` que tecnicamente pode ser substituído por:

   ```css
   float:left;
   display:block;
   ```

   O resultado final é o mesmo, só precisar de garantir que limpas o `float` na tua `ul` fazendo uso da propriedade `clear:both;` de forma a manter o *flow* que já tens no documento.